# renderer undefined when using plain three.js code with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm trying to use plain three.js with a react component to create a basic scene with a cube.
The canvas displays a green cube in the middle, but I still get the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'renderer')`.

Interestingly, when I do `console.log(this)` inside of `animate`, this is the output:
[image]

I've tried looking into tutorials like [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/best-way-to-integrate-plain-three-js-inside-a-react-app/27049) but it's not working.

here's my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';

export class ThreeViewer {
  constructor(canvasRef) {
    this.canvas = canvasRef;
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasRef, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(cube);
    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    this.animate();
  }
  animate() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  }

}

export default class ObjectViewer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.canvas.current;
    this.threeViewer = new ThreeViewer(canvas);
  }
  render() {
    return <canvas id="3dviewer" ref={this.canvas}></canvas>;
  }
}
```

Comment: With your setup, you need to run `requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)